# bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior is givin me a null object

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

I have a problem with a Bottom Navigation drawer, I mean I want to set a navigation drawer from my bottom bar so I try to use a BottomAppBar and I set my navigation view, this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C4C4C4">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrim"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_apoya_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_apoya"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my NavigationView I set this parameter:

> app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"

```
So this is my code:

    navigationViewTest = findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_apoya_test);
            bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar);
            bottomAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(this);
    
            bottomSheetBehavior.from(navigationViewTest);
            //bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(ActionBar);
//This line is where I have the problem
            bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
    
                    if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivityApoyaLogin.this, "Expandido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
    
                    if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivityApoyaLogin.this, "Oculto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
    
                    // Si tuvieramos un float button aqui lo ocultariamos
    
                }
    
            });
```

But when I try to run my app I'm geting this error:

```
2022-09-01 18:33:59.866 11708-11708/com.seccion.seccin15hibrida E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.seccion.seccin15hibrida, PID: 11708
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.seccion.seccin15hibrida/com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.uiCajaSession.InicioCajaA.CajaApoyaBeta.MainActivityApoyaLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior$BottomSheetCallback)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior$BottomSheetCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.uiCajaSession.InicioCajaA.CajaApoyaBeta.MainActivityApoyaLogin.onCreate(MainActivityApoyaLogin.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

Comment: Initialize bottomSheetBehaviour !

Comment: Actually I did in this line -> bottomSheetBehavior.from(navigationViewTest);

Comment: What is bottomSheetBehaviour in your layout?

Comment: Well this is my first time try to show a navigation drawer from bottom bar, so my bottomSheetBehaviour is this -> app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

Change

```
bottomSheetBehavior.from(navigationViewTest);
```

To

```
bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(navigationViewTest);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did knew what was wrong